# Como criar um objeto vazio no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Com um array é possível fazer isto:

```
$arrayVazio = array();
$arrayVazio[key1][var1] = "PHP";
```

É possível fazer isto com um objeto:

```
(object)$objetoVazio = "";
$objetoVazio->key1->var1 = "PHP";
```

Comment: Tem uma pergunta no stackoverflow em ingles exatamente igual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434368/how-to-define-an-empty-object-in-php

Comment: É interessante nós criarmos no SOpt também porque nem todo mundo tem o conhecimento em inglês. Também temos que ver que esta resposta é antiga e temos que dar espaço para respostas atualizadas, como a do Anderson.

Comment: @Everson Concordo com o Velasco, toda pergunta trazida ao SOpt que já existe no SOen tem o intuito de trazer conhecimento, o SOpt não é filho do SOen, cada comunidade é uma, falam do mesmo assunto mas não tem ligação direta, aqui o foco é um publico alvo, no caso nativos do idioma português

Comment: Por isso foi colocado nos comentários ;)

Comment: É que o comentário tinha soado algo diferente @Everson, mas entendi agora ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como diego sugeriu é possível criar um objeto usando `stdClass`, ficaria algo como:

```
<?php

$class = new stdClass;
$class->key1->key2 = 1;

var_dump($class);
```

No entanto devo alerta-los de que ao fazer isto você irá emitir um `warning` semelhante a isto:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Não é um "erro fatal", é apenas um `Warn`, não afeta a execução do script diretamente, no entanto podem ocorrer diversos *efeitos colaterais*, ainda mais se você tiver um *handler* para manipular os erros do PHP, ou algum outro script de terceiros que faz alguma checagem, tipo se houve algum erro anteriormente e então só processaria se não houverem erros, é algo **bem relativo**, como eu disse são *efeitos colateiras*, não significa que vão ocorrer a qualquer momento, só significa que *podem talvez* ocorrer.

Então uma maneira que devo sugerir para criar um objeto seria usando talvez um array e fazendo o `cast` (com `(object)`):

```
<?php

$foo = (object) array(
     'key1' => (object) array(
          'key2' => 2
      )
);

var_dump($foo);
```

Ou poderia criar uma checagem para ver se a chave existe, para então adicionar itens ao `stdClass`:

```
<?php

$foo = new stdClass;

if (!isset($foo->key1)) {
     $foo->key1 = new stdClass;
}

$foo->key1->key2 = 1;

var_dump($foo);
```

Isto são exemplos bem "crus", mas é para entender a lógica, algo que pode ser interessante seria criar algo semelhante a um `XPath` para `arrays` ou `stdClass` , ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
/*
- &$obj Passa o objeto como referencia
- $path informa o caminho desejado
- $value informa o valor desejado
*/

function setPath(&$obj, $path, $value) {
    $paths = explode('.', $path); //Pega todas dimensões desejadas
    $last = array_pop($paths); //Pega a ultima dimensão

    $isArray = is_array($obj); //Verifica se é um array como padrão
    $current = $obj; //Objecto atual da primeira dimensão

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (!isset($current->$path)) {
            $current->$path = $isArray ? array() : new \stdClass;
        }

        $current = $current->$path;
    }

    $current->$last = $value; //Define o valor na ultima dimensão
}

$foo = new stdClass;

setPath($foo, 'key1.key2.key3', 'Olá Mundo!');

var_dump($foo);
```

Que resultaria nisto:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["key1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["key2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      ["key3"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Esse exemplo é bem simples, claro que não é perfeito, o objetivo dele é mostrar de maneira simples como fazer isto, você pode melhorar adaptar e fazer como desejar.

É claro que se você tiver total controle sobre teus scripts e as bibliotecas de terceiros que vier a usar ou frameworks e tiver plena certeza que `Warnings` não causarão *efeitos colaterais*, então **será mais que o suficiente** usar apenas isto:

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->key1->key2->key3 = 'Olá mundo!';
```

Answer (score 6):

No PHP 7 é possível ainda utilizar classes anônimas, inclusive definindo métodos para tal objeto:

```
$obj = new class {
    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->key1 = new stdClass();
        $this->key1->var1 = "SOpt";
    }

    public function getKey1 ()
    {
        return $this->key1;
    }

    public function __toString ()
    {
        return "Objeto criado com classe anônima";
    }
};

// Acessando o atributo diretamente:
echo $obj->key1->var1, PHP_EOL;

// Acessando o atributo através do método get:
echo $obj->getKey1()->var1, PHP_EOL;

// Chamando o método __toString do objeto:
echo $obj, PHP_EOL;

// Exibindo a classe do objeto:
echo get_class($obj), PHP_EOL;
```

A saída será:

```
SOpt
SOpt
Objeto criado com classe anônima
class@anonymous/home/dJc0UT/prog.php0x2b8e54b21146
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/GyttiA).

Answer (score 2):

Standard class. Leia mais em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php

```
$class = new stdClass();
```